# Compare cells in two tables return color

Tags: php, mysql

How can I compare two cells in two different tables in an `if`?

Let's say I have a table **t1** like this:

```
|id   |name     |number   |week |
|1    |Ross     |2        |14   |
|2    |Brad     |3        |14   |
```

And then I have a table **t2** like:

```
|week |rightnum  |
|14   |2         |
```

I would like to select the two tables and if the number is equal to the *rightnum* then it should `echo` the number in green. I've tried:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2 on t1.week = t2.week WHERE t1.week = 14
```

and then:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
  if (t1.number == t2.rightnum) {
    echo "<font color="green">".$row['k1']."<br />"; }
  else { echo $row['k1']; } };
```

Comment: `(t1.number == t2.rightnum)` what do you expect from this one? This won't work in PHP. You've already done this "IF" condition in your SQL statement, you don't need to do it again in PHP (and even if you had to, its completly wrong. You can't access SQL objects in an PHP if-else condition.) Also, can you please be a bit more precise: What doesn't work? Do you get any error?

Comment: @twinfriends I'm aware that it didn't work - you don't have to point that out. If I knew how to make it work, I wouldn't have asked in here.

Comment: Wow, calm down dude. It was only a question what you expect from your condition. Sorry that I'm not one of those guy who provides you a free answer. I try to help users, but you've to show me that you also try to learn something, thats why I ask... because then I understand what you thought and I can explain your mistakes better. But yeah anyway. if you're not interested, have a nice day and good luck with your problem :)

Comment: @twinfriends Yeah sorry about that. Think I've read your comment the wrong way in my frustration.. my bad!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the application, but if you really want the value calculations in a SQL query, you can do that.

First, start by listing more explicitly the columns you want.  Then use a `case` to get the color:

```
SELECT t1.week,
       (CASE WHEN t1.number = t2.rightnum THEN 'green' END) as color
FROM t1 JOIN
     t2 
     ON t1.week = t2.week
WHERE t1.week = 14;
```

Comment: Should I still use `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))` to echo them, because I can't get it to echo anything now..

Comment: It won't change the color when i `echo $row['number']` . It's just normal color.

Comment: @DanielJensen . . . This just returns the color.  What you do with it is up to your application code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
if ($row['number'] == $row['rightnum'])
$color = 'green';
else {
$color = 'red'; }
```

and then added this to the line where i post the numbers:

```
echo '<font color="'.$color.'">'.$row['number'].'</font>';
```